# Sort vector of objects using extra parameter with functor

Tags: c++, sorting, operator-overloading

I am trying to sort a vector of objects. The object (InOutPair) is declared as follows:

```
// Pair that contains pointers to x vector and y string
class InOutPair {
    std::pair< std::vector<double>*, std::string* > pair_;

public:
    InOutPair(std::vector<double>* x, std::string* y) { pair_ = make_pair(x,y); }
    std::vector<double> x() const { return *pair_.first; }
    std::string y() const { return *pair_.second; }
};
```

I have a vector of `InOutPair`s called `pairs_` and I'm trying to sort this vector using an extra attribute using a functor `XSorter`:

```
class XSorter
{
    int index_;

public:

    XSorter(int index) { index_ = index;}
    bool operator() (const InOutPair& left, const InOutPair& right) const {
        return left.x()[index_] < right.x()[index_];
    }
};

//...

int attr = 1;
sort(pairs_.begin(), pairs_.end(), XSorter(attr)); // <--error occurs here
```

Unfortunately I'm getting the following error when I try to build:

```
passing ‘const InOutPair’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘InOutPair& InOutPair::operator=(const InOutPair&)’ discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
```

I'm unsure what is wrong? I have made the overloaded `operator()` function const, along with member function `InOutPair::x()`. Thanks!

EDIT: 
Error occurs in stl_algo.h:

```
  /// This is a helper function for the sort routine.
  template<typename _RandomAccessIterator, typename _Compare>
    void
    __insertion_sort(_RandomAccessIterator __first,
             _RandomAccessIterator __last, _Compare __comp)
    {
      if (__first == __last) return;

      for (_RandomAccessIterator __i = __first + 1; __i != __last; ++__i)
    {
      if (__comp(*__i, *__first))
        {
          typename iterator_traits<_RandomAccessIterator>::value_type
        __val = _GLIBCXX_MOVE(*__i);
          _GLIBCXX_MOVE_BACKWARD3(__first, __i, __i + 1);
          *__first = _GLIBCXX_MOVE(__val);        // <-- error occurs here
        }
      else
        std::__unguarded_linear_insert(__i, __comp);
    }
    }
```

Comment: Wild guess: this error would make sense if you were trying to sort a **constant** vector of `InOutPair`s.

Comment: In which line you get the error. Code posted here looks OK. There should be some underlying code which you haven't provided. In particular there is no operator = used in your code especially on `const InOutPair`, unless your vector is const as Wintermute suggested...

Comment: @Wintermute, the vector of `InOutPair`s, `pairs_` is a member variable and is not const. @Wojciech, see the edit I have made in the post.

Comment: Is the member function in which `std::sort` is called declared `const`?